# Unable to click custom control in design time

Tags: delphi, custom-controls, mouse, delphi-xe2, design-time

I'm building a custom control (inherited from `TCustomControl`) in Delphi XE2 (and have had this issue in other controls of mine) and in design time, I'm unable to click them. I know it has to do with the mouse capture, and catching the mouse events and handling them differently in design time than run time, but I do not know how to properly accommodate for this. In other words, of the many work arounds I can think of, I can not decide which one is the proper (or most efficient) way.

I'm sure there must be some very simple standard to this, most likely utilizing the `ControlStyle` or `CreateParams` but do not know what.

In this particular control (and I have not seen a pattern in this issue), I am capturing messages including `WM_NCHITTEST` and `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`. In design-time, the control is 100% active as if it were run time, and when clicking, it's instead performing the run time code.

I have a feeling it's in my hit test message handler, so here's that code (some things renamed):

```
procedure TMyCustomControl.WMNCHitTest(var Message: TWMNCHitTest);
var
  P: TPoint;
  Poly: TPoints;
  X: Integer;
  I: TMyCollectionItem;
  Ch: Bool; //Need to improve invalidation
begin
  Ch:= False;
  P:= ScreenToClient(Point(Message.Pos.X, Message.Pos.Y));
  for X := 0 to Items.Count - 1 do begin
    I:= Items[X];
    Poly:= I.Points;
    FMouseIndex:= -1;
    FMouseState:= bmNone;
    if PointInPolygon(P, Poly) then begin //checks if point is within polygon
      FMouseIndex:= X;
      FMouseState:= bmHover;
      Ch:= True;
      Break;
    end;
  end;
  if Ch then Invalidate;
end;
```

And also my control's constructor (stripped):

```
constructor TMyCustomControl.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  ControlStyle:= ControlStyle - [csDesignInteractive];
end;
```

Comment: To be more specific, this control is a horizontal (or vertical) list of items, or arrows actually. Each item is drawn as a polygon one after another, and the space around each item is considered nothing (background). When hovering over an item, I'm highlighting that item (and performing other internal references to that item). I also plan to implement focus on individual list items as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

But of course you are right. You are not returning anything in the `WM_NCHITTEST` handler. Your `Mmessage.Result` is '0' (HTNOWHERE) when your handler is called and you are not assigning anything else to it.

Either call `inherited` at some point, or implement your logic and return (set the Message.Result) `HTCLIENT` for the points you consider to be the interior of your control.

It that's already the desired behavior at runtime, you can include a design-time check (but I guess you should be doing all that calculation for a reason):

```
if csDesigning in ComponentState then
  Msg.Result := HTCLIENT;
```

Comment: +1 `csDesigning` did the trick - I knew it was something like that but I was looking in `ControlState` rather than `ComponentState` which is why I could not find my answer to begin with. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The official way to support mouse interactions at design-time is to respond with a non-zero result to the `CM_DESIGNHITTEST` message. The component will then receive normal mouse messages.

Comment: AFAICS CM_DESIGNHITTEST is sent only when the control returns HTCLIENT for WM_NCHITTEST. BTW, I didn't quite understand how this is supposed to work by looking at the VCL source, it is also not documented. I returned 0 for a test control and could not observe any different behavior.

Comment: You don't need to handle `WM_NCHITTEST`, let the default handler manage that for you. Most controls don't need to support design-time interactions, so they do not respond to `CM_DESIGNHITTEST`, but a few native controls do, such as those that allow visual sizing of columns instead of using the Object Inspector, for example.